# PowerShell script to get the ShowInEditForm property for a site column. i do not want to use PnP PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, sharepoint-online-powershell

I am trying this script to get the ShowInEditForm property of a site column and then set it to False:-

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://****-admin.sharepoint.com/

Get-SPOSite -Identity https://***.sharepoint.com/


$column = Get-SPOField -Identity "CarNumber"
```

but i am getting this error:-

```
Get-SPOField : The term 'Get-SPOField' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

any advice please?

Hints:-

1. I know i can do this using PnP Power shell, but i can not use PnP Powershell due to security restrictions.
2. and we have MFA enabled for the account

Comment: Get-spofield is an alias for get-pnpfield.

Comment: @Christoffer the accepted answer use an approach which does not work if we have MFA enabled.. which will not work for us

Comment: Which were not stated in the initial question.

Comment: @Christoffer yes i edit my question

Comment: @Christoffer but our customer does not allow us to use PnP Power shell due to security restrictions